# select between two dates with an unformated date

Tags: mysql, date, select

I hope my English is not so bad, my problem is on entering a query for a specific month , just taking the month , for example :

I have a date picker that gives me the following: in February 2015 , then I want to know how to perform the query so that the first of the month Begin to 31 thereof.

This is and example of query:

```
 SELECT * from expenses WHERE date BETWEEN February 2015 and in February 2015 AND ID LIKE ' TEL- %' "
```

Comment: DO you have any example data and your table structure you can post?

Comment: Yes, look
http://puu.sh/gdzAI/76902ca11f.png

Comment: Can you post an sql fiddle? Still need example data, an image doesn't help that much

Comment: http://puu.sh/gdA0P/2dc9b112a5.png sry if i post only images, but i have these, but I need to filter by full months

Comment: Columns need to be changed to DATE or DATETIME in order for the between to work

Comment: Please show us what '$date1' looks like. Any example is good. Do you want all the entries for the 'year and month' as given in '$date1'? i.e. one months worth of records?

Comment: SELECT * from expenses
WHERE date BETWEEN February 2015
and February 2015 AND ID LIKE ' TEL- %' "

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and sry for the bad redacting of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In datepick you can salect the date format [http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats].

**jQuery**

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

To compare two dates they are to be in the format 2015-02-26.

So, or you change the date format of Datepicker or you made a script to do that like, for example, if the date is in the format 26/02/2015:

**PHP**

```
function fecha_to_date($fecha){

    $campos=explode("/", $fecha);
    $date=$campos[2]."-".$campos[1]."-".$campos[0];     
    return $date;


}
```

**MySQL**

```
SELECT * FROM gastos WHERE fecha BETWEEN $fecha AND $fecha + INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND Id LIKE 'TEL-%'
```

So, if your date is 2015-02-26, you will get the data between 2015-02-26 AND 2015-03-26

Comment: Thanks, i just need to change the format and add 30 days to the date.

Comment: SELECT * FROM gastos WHERE  fecha BETWEEN $fecha AND $fecha + INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND Id LIKE 'TEL-%'

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the column as DATE o DATETIME to compare dates and use:
**fecha between fecha_1 AND fecha_2** OR  **fecha>=fecha_1 AND fecha<=fecha_2**

Comment: The column is already defined as DATE :c, my problem is that the date format I'm asking is different than I have in the database , for example

SELECT * from expenses
WHERE date BETWEEN February 2015
and in February 2015 AND ID LIKE ' TEL- %' "